# Flatlist doesn't render an array of Objects

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, rxjs, react-native-flatlist

Hello everybody i'm trying to render a list of objects to rapresent some letters, taken from a custom keyboard. my flatlist look like this:

```
<FlatList
horizontal={true}
data = {keyList}
renderItem = {({item}) => 
    <View style={styles.singleBlock}>
        <Text style={styles.textBlock}>{item.letter}</Text>
    </View>
    }
keyExtractor = {myKey}
/>
```

the data is taken from my state:

```
    const [keyList, setKeyList] = useState([
        {
            'letter': "",
            'state': "nonIndovinato",
            'id': 1
        },
        {
            'letter': "",
            'state': "Indovinato",
            'id': 2
        },
        {
            'letter': "",
            'state': "Indovinato",
            'id': 3
        },
        {
            'letter': "",
            'state': "Indovinato",
            'id': 4
        },
        {
            'letter': "",
            'state': "Indovinato",
            'id': 5
        }
    ]);
```

and updated by update function:

```
    const updateData = (key) => {
        const index = keyList.findIndex(item => item.id === key.id);

        if(index === -1) return;

        const item = keyList[index];

        const updatedItem = {...item, letter: key.letter};

        const updatedArray = keyList;

        updatedArray[index] = updatedItem;

        setKeyList(updatedArray);
    };
```

the key value is something as follow:

```
{
    'letter': 'A',
    'id': 1
}
```

the data i see with console.log is right, for example if i press T it look like this:

```
{letter: 'T', state: 'nonIndovinato', id: 1},
{letter: '', state: 'Indovinato', id: 2},
{letter: '', state: 'Indovinato', id: 3},
{letter: '', state: 'Indovinato', id: 4},
{letter: '', state: 'Indovinato', id: 5}
```

the application look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhQiq.jpg
the upper part is the structure where it should be displayed the data, the lower is the expected result with mockup data.

if you need the style:

```
    singleBlock: {
        backgroundColor: 'grey',
        width: width/6,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 1,
        marginTop: '5%',
        marginBottom: '5%',
        marginRight: 2,
        borderRadius: 1
    },
    textBlock: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: width/10,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
```

Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: It seems like you try to render straight out of state. Do somethiong like this: `const data = keylist` and map over `data`

Comment: What is `myKey`? Your keyExtractor is not defined.

Comment: What is the value of `width`. Currently it is undefined. `the data i see with console.log is right, for example if i press T it look like this:` The way you do that is missing in your snippet.

Comment: myKey is const myKey = (item) => {
 return item.id;
};

Comment: import {  Dimensions }  from "react-native";                                                                   
 var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

Comment: How are you calling `updateData`?

Comment: in my useEffect as follow: useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = comunicationService.onMessage().subscribe(key => {
   if(key) {
    updateData(key);
   } else{
    setKeyList([]);
   }
  });

Comment: What is `comunicationService`?

Comment: const comunicationService = {
    sendMessage: key => {
  
  i++

  subject.next({ 
  letter: key,
  id: i,
   }
  )},
    clearMessages: () => subject.next(),
    onMessage: () => subject.asObservable()
};

Comment: i'm sorry for the missing code but i thought it was a long thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are updating your state is not correct. Try the following.

```js
const updateData = (key) => {
        const index = keyList.findIndex(item => item.id === key.id);

        if(index === -1) return;

        const item = keyList[index];
        const updatedItem = {...item, letter: key.letter};


        let updatedArray = [...keyList];
        updatedArray[index] = updatedItem;
        
        setKeyList(updatedArray);
};
```

Comment: that's better, now it render something but only one letter at time, if i press another key the previous get cancelled, what can it be?

Comment: Do you press both keys at the same time?

Comment: nope, one at time